# Change Android Map rotation center

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-mapview

I need to create application similar to Google Map Navigator, where the navigation arrow is placed at the bottom of screen not at the center.With the code below I'am able to offset the map center to my arrow position but the rotation is still done around the point at the center of the screen.

```
  float zoom = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
  double sizePerDegree = 256.0*Math.pow(2, zoom) / 170.0;
  double mHeight = (double) mMapView.getHeight();
  double mHeight_30p = 30.0*mHeight / 100.0;
  double degree_30p  = mHeight_30p / sizePerDegree ;
  final LatLng offsetedLatLng = new LatLng( realLocation.latitude + degree_30p  , realLocation.longitude );
```

Is there any approaches to rotate map around any specific point on screen but not by center ?

Thanks in advance!